# Multiple regression with dependent variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction

I have a dataset with 3 variables (X,Y and Z) and I want to find the best estimates for the constants a,b,c & d. I have been looking into multiregression analysis, but that does not seem to work for this more complicated formula.

> Y = (a + b * Z) * X^(c + d * Z)

Someone got any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to linearize the problem. It's not possible. You have to use non-linear regression in this case.

Comment: How would I approach this. I do know how to perform non-linear regression, however I do not have experience with 3 variables and would not know where to start.

Comment: What stat package are you using?

Comment: Python, but I could use any

Comment: Take a look at [this R doc](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonlinear-regression.pdf). It has an example in it. and a theory if you want to implement the thing in your code manually.